# Cant receive mail from gmail (2)

Tags: linux, gmail, postfix

I've noticed mails being sent from my gmail account to a mailbox on a centos 7 server are not arriving their destination, but no bounce message returned as well.

This is what I've found in maillog:

> Jun  1 14:59:26 myhost postfix/smtpd[31043]: warning: No server certs
>   available. TLS won't be enabled
>
> Jun  1 14:59:26 myhost postfix/smtpd[31043]: connect from
>   mail-wi0-f176.google.com[209.85.212.176]
>
> Jun  1 14:59:26 myhost postfix/smtpd[31043]: lost connection after
>   STARTTLS from mail-wi0-f176.google.com[209.85.212.176]
>
> Jun  1 14:59:26 myhost postfix/cleanup[31045]: 5C764B61E54:
>   message-id=<20150601125926.5C764B61E54@myserver.host>
>
> Jun  1 14:59:26 myhost postfix/smtpd[31043]: disconnect from
>   mail-wi0-f176.google.com[209.85.212.176] Jun  1 14:59:26 myhost
>   postfix/qmgr[25681]: 5C764B61E54: from=,
>   size=953, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
>
> Jun  1 14:59:26 myhost postfix/local[31047]: 5C764B61E54:
>   to=, orig_to=, relay=local,
>   delay=0.44, delays=0.04/0.01/0/0.39, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered
>   to command: /usr/bin/procmail-wrapper -o -a $DOMAIN -d $LOGNAME)
>
> Jun  1 14:59:26 myhost  postfix/qmgr[25681]: 5C764B61E54: removed

There is a self signed certificate on this server, and it used to work until today...

I've also added these lines to mail.cf - but it didn't help:

> smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3
>
> smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3

Comment: It says sent, and delivered to command procmail-wrapper. Is there a log for procmail-wrapper?

Comment: It generates an error message and sends it to root@myserver....

Answer (score -1):

This is one solution (a bad one) - I've turned off TLS and now it works, but I have no TLS....

Comment: Removing TLS solved the problem for me. So it is a complete solution. I don't like it, and once a better solution will come (that will make tls work with gmail) I'll be happier. that's why I didn't accept my own answer, but if someone encounters this problem - this is one emergency step that helps.